# scalable loadbalancer for jetty server

Tags: java, apache, jetty, load-balancing

I am creating an application and I want to create it with applications that are fast but also scale. I use java jetty for my servers, cassandra for my database and solr as search engine. What should I use as a loadbalancer infront of the jetty servers so that the whole setup can scale. I've read about mod_jk and apache but I've also read that it doesn't scale to many machines due to beeing programmed in C. What should I use? Should I try and program something myself in java? I want to use non sticky sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apache would work fine as a reverse proxy, its really more about with what you or your team is familiar with.  Without sticky sessions its pretty easy for most things to work.  [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) or [Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) is probably what your looking for though if need something bigger.  To scale it horizontally it is more a trick of not having sticky sessions (which you already have covered) so fronting it with dns round robining would work.

Really not sure what you mean by programming being in C as it really doesn't have anything to do with scaling things horizontally or vertically.  Thats more of an architecture thing then the language used to implement it.